# JS how to know which function is called when i click a button element

Tags: javascript

For example, I have an html snippet:

```
<input id="aps123456" class="bt-sb bt-blue" type="button">
```

If I clicked the button, the button will trigger a function to do some procedure, maybe submit a form. But I don't know which function is called. Because there're too many minified scripts in a file. I wonder if there's a way to locate this function precisely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome debugger offers to show bound events :

[image]

Comment: No matter what is clicked on, this appears to show the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/visual+event+2) bookmarklet.

This should allow you to see which function are bound to the event handler for your button.